# How to do URL encryption in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I am making an application in PHP in which user names are showing in URL like
www.mysite.com/user/shahroze

I want to encrypt the name something like that
www.mysite.com/user/ZxtccQO58

how can i do that to save my sensitive data?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems security through obscurity.

Comment: Create a unique hash/code when creating the user, then in your SQL check if username or code is the same as the $_GET value. As @grooveplex stated, this isn't security, it's obscurity. While this may made it harder to public users to find the page, it won't be impossible.

Comment: You can use the `base64_encode` / `base64_decode` functions.

Comment: You gain no security at all from doing this.

Comment: Perhaps you only need some quick and dirty obfuscation, don't do  the base64 as this is not even considered obfuscation, and perhaps use a hashing method with some daily random salt that you store with the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS, everything except the site address is encrypted in transit. Note that the entire URL will probably be in the server logs.

Answer (score -1):

For each user have a column in database with a random string and use it in URL (when adding random string for the user you will have to check if it's taken or not so that it doesn't come to overlapping). Although that will work, there is no need to do that because it's secure enough without it, but if you really want to hide the usernames this is the way to go.